# how to apply a list of functions on a specific column in a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have a data frame like

| river | discharge |
| --- | --- |
| river1 | 500 |
| river1 | 450 |
| river1 | 200 |
| river1 | 250 |
| river2 | 375 |
| river2 | 235 |
| river2 | 130 |
| river2 | 250 |

I want to apply the following list of function to the column discharge ..

```
f <- list(
  mean = function(x, ...) mean(x), 
  Q50 = function(x, ...) lfquantile(x, exc.freq = 0.5),
  Q95 = function(x, ...) lfquantile(x, exc.freq = 0.95),
  Q90 = function(x, ...) lfquantile(x, exc.freq = 0.9),
  Q70 = function(x, ...) lfquantile(x, exc.freq = 0.7),
)
```

in the end I am supposed to have a table like this :

| river | mean | Q50 | Q95 | Q90 | Q70 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| river1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| river2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| rivern |  |  |  |  |  |

I do not have any idea how to do that :(

Comment: Can you show the package of `lfquantile` function

Comment: Must you summarize your data using this list of functions? If not, look into the `dplyr` package’s `group_by` and `summarize` functions. In other words, is your goal in this question obtaining the final output, or figuring out how to use this list of functions?

Answer (score 0):

If we have all the functions available, then use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
imap_dfc(f, ~ df1 %>% 
    group_by(river) %>%
    reframe(!! .y := .x(discharge)))
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but it seems that there is not a reframe function  in r!!!!

Comment: @Faranakomidi it is in the newer version of dplyr.  Or switch with `summarise` (summarise may get deprecated though)

Comment: summarise dose not work in this case since it is not only quantile and mean some times i have more complicated  functions .. so I can not have a vector I have to have a function and I summarise as far as I know is not usable for functions .

Comment: @Faranakomidi this is based on your example and the output of the functions it returns.  If you have functions that return a different object, then wrap with `list` on the `summarise` output

Comment: I solve it by transform() somehow ..however it is not a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use group_by() function and apply the list of statistics to calculate the summaries and no need to write functions:

library(dplyr)

```
 df %>% 
  group_by(river)%>% 
  summarize(
    mean = mean(discharge),
    q50 = quantile(discharge, 0.50),
    q95 = quantile(discharge, 0.95),
    q90 = quantile(discharge, 0.90),
    q70 = quantile(discharge, 0.70)
  )
```

and the output is:

```
 river   mean  q50   q95   q90   q70
 river1  350   350   492   485   455 
 river2  248   242   356   338   262
```

Comment: summarise dose not work in this case since it is not only quantile and mean sometimes i have more complicated functions .. so I can not have a vector I have to have a function and I summarise as far as I know is not usable for functions

Comment: You wrote in your question that you want to apply the following list of function to the column discharge. I do not see:   'sometimes I have more complicated functions ' in your question. if the complicated function is already available no need to write function. Can you explain what is the function that complicated and you need to include in the function list?

Answer (score 0):

A **base R** approach. Replacing `lfquantile` with `quantile` for this example.

```
func <- list(mean = function (x, ...) mean(x), 
Q50 = function (x, ...) quantile(x, probs = 0.5), 
Q95 = function (x, ...) quantile(x, probs = 0.95), 
Q90 = function (x, ...) quantile(x, probs = 0.9), 
Q70 = function (x, ...) quantile(x, probs = 0.7))
```

```
setNames(aggregate(discharge ~ river, df, function(x) 
  setNames(sapply(names(func), function(nm) 
    func[[nm]](x)), names(func))), c("river", ""))
   river   mean    Q50    Q95    Q90    Q70
1 river1 350.00 350.00 492.50 485.00 455.00
2 river2 247.50 242.50 356.25 337.50 262.50
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(river = c("river1", "river1", "river1", "river1", 
"river2", "river2", "river2", "river2"), discharge = c(500L, 
450L, 200L, 250L, 375L, 235L, 130L, 250L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

func <- list(mean = function (x, ...) mean(x), 
             Q50 = function (x, ...) quantile(x, probs = 0.5), 
             Q95 = function (x, ...) quantile(x, probs = 0.95), 
             Q90 = function (x, ...) quantile(x, probs = 0.9), 
             Q70 = function (x, ...) quantile(x, probs = 0.7))

df %>%
  group_by(river) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(discharge), func)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   river   mean   Q50   Q95   Q90   Q70
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 river1  350   350   492.  485   455 
#> 2 river2  248.  242.  356.  338.  262.

df %>%
  group_by(river) %>%
  summarise(across(discharge, func))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   river  discharge_mean discharge_Q50 discharge_Q95 discharge_Q90 discharge_Q70
#>   <chr>           <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 river1           350           350           492.          485           455 
#> 2 river2           248.          242.          356.          338.          262.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

## EDIT

since the `quantile` function is vectorized, you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

func1 <- function(x){
  qnts <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.5,0.95,0.9,0.7))
  qnts <- setNames(qnts, paste0('Q', c(50,95,90,70)))
  data.frame(mean = mean(x), as.list(qnts))
}

df %>%
  summarise(across(discharge, func1, .unpack = TRUE), .by = river)
#>    river discharge_mean discharge_Q50 discharge_Q95 discharge_Q90 discharge_Q70
#> 1 river1          350.0         350.0        492.50         485.0         455.0
#> 2 river2          247.5         242.5        356.25         337.5         262.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>